# Add view to layout inside fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, actionbarsherlock

is it possible to add view to layout inside fragment. My fragment code looks like this, but i m getting crash while adding.

I want to add views dynamically to linear layout inside fragment.

```
package com.emergreen.goresq;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class GRPlacesFragment extends SherlockFragment{

    GRMyPlaces grmp;
    View myview;

     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grpl,
                                         container, false);

            myview = view;
            return view;
        }


     public void addPlaces(context gr)
     {
         grmp = gr;

         LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) myview.findViewById(R.id.pid);

         Button button = new Button(grmp);
         button.setText("Testing button");



         ll.addView(button);


     }

}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `addPlaces` method?

Comment: The code you provided is correct, the error is somewhere else, please provide more as previously mentioned.

Comment: Hi, add places is calling from the sherlockfragment activity. i m doing getsupportmanager().fragmentransistion.add("layoutID",fragment).

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the following which seems to work for me when I used fragments for a project:

```
public class GRPlacesFragment extends SherlockFragment {

...
private View myView;

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grpl, container, false);

        return myView;
    }


 ...
```

}

Something seems to be amiss in your assignments of your variables, since you change between using "view" and "myview".

You should furthermore ensure that your two variables are private and thereby only accesible to this specific class.

Tell me whether or not this helps.

Comment: How can i get the access to memeber of view inside the fragment class?. i need to add view dynamically. for that i need to have access to linerlayout present in view which you have inflated.